# VBA - For loops only printing last item

Tags: excel, vba

I'm messing around with a workbook and trying to automatically populate what I have in a row into a column.

The row number I'm copying from is twice the amount of rows I can fit into the number of columns I'm printing in the new worksheet, so whenever the row number hits the maximum number of columns it creates a new worksheet and prints into that.

It works for the first number in the new worksheet, but then once it reaches the `ElseIf y > 11` line then it's only printing the last number in the array.

```
Sub ColumnToRow()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim myarray() as Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ReDim myarray(11 To 30)
    For x = 11 To 30
        myarray(x) = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value
        y = x - 10
    Next x

    For y = 1 To 20
        If y = 11 Then
            z = 1

            Worksheets("0049-0050").Copy After:=Worksheets("0049-0050")
            Set sht = ActiveSheet
            sht.Range(Cells(50, z), Cells(40, y - 1)).ClearContents
            sht.Cells(50, z).Value = myarray(y + 10)

            z  = z + 1 'Typist's note:  so, "z = 2"?
        ElseIf y > 11 Then
            For z = 2 To 10
                sht.Cells(50, z).Value = myarray(y + 10)
            Next z
        Else
            Sheets("0049-0050").Cells(50, y).Value = myarray(y + 10)
        End If
    Next y

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq7D1.png)

Comment: What is "ElseIf y > 11" referring to?

Comment: please put the code as text and not a picture, we cannot copy paste a picture.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53673036/edit) and post your code as text.

Comment: A quick note, make sure to qualify the `CELLS()` reference within `RANGE()`: `sht.Range(sht.Cells(50, z), sht.Cells(50, y-1)).ClearContents`.  Also, don't use `ActiveSheet`, especially if your macro can touch multiple sheets. Switch that with the actual sheet name.

Comment: @BruceWayne I wasn't sure how to go about naming the worksheet variable from the newly created worksheet. - Thanks

Comment: @tk78 The ElseIf y > 11 is referring to the number of columns that the values can be transposed into. The row count is 20 but the amount of columns is 10, therefore whenever the amount of rows is greater than 10, then a new worksheet will have to be copied/created and the rest of the values will go onto that newly created worksheet.

Comment: Step through the code with `F8`, and see if you can see why and when it starts acting unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

@BruceWayne I figured out what my issue was, I was trying to run a for loop within the ElseIf Statement, which caused it to completed that nested loop without running the outside loop, so I just did a loop increment using the integer instead:

```
Sub ColumnToRow()

Dim X As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myarray() As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ReDim myarray(11 To 30)
    For X = 11 To 30
        myarray(X) = ActiveSheet.Cells(X, 1).Value
        y = X - 10
    Next X


    For y = 1 To 20
        If y = 11 Then
         z = 1
            Worksheets("0049-0050").Copy After:=Worksheets("0049-0050")
            Set sht = ActiveSheet
            sht.Range(sht.Cells(50, z), sht.Cells(50, y - 1)).ClearContents
            sht.Cells(50, z).Value = myarray(y + 10)

        ElseIf y > 11 Then

            sht.Cells(50, z).Value = myarray(y + 10)

        Else
            Sheets("0049-0050").Cells(50, y).Value = myarray(y + 10)
        End If
            z = z + 1
    Next y

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

- Thanks